# AWS EC2 : mysql docker fails with /bin/bash: /entrypoint.sh: Permission denied

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

```
docker pull mysql/mysql-server:5.7

docker run --name=mysql1 -d mysql/mysql-server:5.7
```

Above two commands run on my local but it fails on aws ec2 instance.

Comment: Which user are you running it as? Is that user added to the Docker group?

Comment: please try sudo docker pull mysql/mysql-server:5.7

sudo docker run --name=mysql1 -d mysql/mysql-server:5.7

Comment: I am running using docker user and yes it is added in Docker group.

Comment: @smraj i have tried the option, still same permission denied.